# Angular website does not load home page(shows blank page) as soon as i login but when i refresh 2 or 3 times then Home page is visible

Tags: angular

When I login to my angular website(production) in first go it does not show my home page still after login but when I do refresh 2 or 3 times then it loads home page.

when first time page loads main.js and runtime.js are not loading and showing error as **net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)**

[image]

but same project is working fine on staging(a testing platform) but not working properly in prod platform.
below are the commands that I use to make build of my project for in stg and prod.

```
 "prod-build": "ng build --configuration production --aot false --build-optimizer=false && npm run post-build",
    "stg-build": "ng build --configuration=stg --aot false --build-optimizer=false && npm run post-build",
```

I do not know what to do to fix  the loading issue in production so that as soon as I login , home page should load.

Comment: You should check the cache settings of your production server. Set it up so that any html files in cache expires after five minutes. In many cases that is the issue.

Comment: Your `index.html` is probably cached. When you generate a new version of your site, the cached `index.html` still points to old js/css that do not exist anymore. This causes the 404 that you see. Given the size of an `index.html`, it should not be cached at all. The configuration depends on your server so you will have to read the doc on that